# How to generate a report of what new , modified or removed documents in sp online monthly

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am looking for a ps that can generate a report monthly of whats changed from a docs perspective, at a site collection level to log all new ly added files, removed, modified files etc. Can someone help me with ps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could get audit log reports in Security & Compliance Center of Microsoft 365 admin center.

1.Get audit log reports manually.

Reference:

[Search the audit log in the Security & Compliance Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide)

2.Get audit log reports by using PowerShell.

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: How to View Audit Log Reports in Security & Compliance Center?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-search-audit-logs-in-security-compliance-center.html#ixzz6YfGTxDXh)